# Когда процесс спит...

Tags: python, распараллеливание

**Доброго времени суток!**

Интересует немного странный, наверное, для многих очевидный вопрос мультипроцессорности. Есть приложение на CPython, которое создает несколько экземпляров классов наследников *multiprocessing.Process* и управляет ими.

Допустим, что возникла ситуация, как на [этой](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdAhs.png) схеме. Четыре процесса выполняются параллельно в данный момент времени. Пятый, шестой, седьмой ждут своей очереди. Все мирно, тихо и тут ВНЕЗАПНО процесс "Process #2" решает немного вздремнуть, передав команду *time.sleep(1)*. Значит *Process #2* приостанавливает выполнение на 1 секунду.

**Вопрос.** Что будет происходить во время сна *Process #2*: *Core #2* будет занято одним из процессов очереди или тупо бездействовать, ожидая завершения сна *Process #2*?

**UPD**: [Пример кода](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdAhs.png)

Comment: Тред во время sleep блокируется. Но я точно не знаю, станет ли проц запускать в это время другой, ожидающий тред, или нет.

Comment: @uzumaxy, откуда у Вас эта самая Queue появилась.

Пример **кода** приведите.

Comment: Если я правильно понял multiprocessing.Process, то другой то просто Process #2 на время будет исключен из списка готовых к выполнению. Поэтому 4 ядра будут делиться между оставшимися процессами.

Comment: Я, конечно, дам самый далекий от ответа комментарий, но не проще ли просто проверить?

Comment: Queue - очередь процессов на выполнение. Реализация системы распределения времени процессора в каждой ОС может быть разная, но выполнять в один момент времени больше процессов, чем поддерживает проц. невозможно, как Я понимаю(без эмуляции; задействования доп. процессоров, в т.ч. графического и прочей лабуды). Потому строиться очередь на выполнение. Она и есть Queue, что изображена на схеме.
Это немного грубовато и неточно, даже если рассматривать ситуацию только в контексте процессов, обделяя вниманием потоки.

Comment: [Пример кода][1]


  [1]: http://pastebin.com/E2UMWace

Comment: С потоками в python проще. GIL позволяет одновременно выполнять только один поток процесса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@uzumaxy](/users/1015/uzumaxy)](/users/1015/uzumaxy), Вы имеете в виду runqueue **в ОС** ???

Насколько я понимаю, Вы запускаете (в примере) 8 независимых процессов без всяких питоновских манагеров.

Если так, то не беспокойтесь. ОС довольно хорошо написаны и не допускают простоя CPU, если есть готовые их использовать процессы.

Более того, если есть *намного больше* процессов, чем доступных процессоров, то время процессора будет выделяться всем этим процессам по очереди (на "справедливой" основе). В Linux такое перераспределение будет проходить 100 раз в секунду, если в системе нет никакой другой (кроме вычислительной) работы.

Comment: Если runqueue - очередь активных процессов, то да - именно про нее речь.
Но, насколько мне известно, при создании нового процесса из-под Python VM, он все-таки обвешивается кучей всяких побрякушек типа собственного GC. Именно потому и спрашиваю. Именно потому в тегах "python".
ОС не позволит простаивать процу, но как-то она ведь обменивается сообщениями с процессами. И если последний решил самозавершиться, то должен про это сообщить планировщику процессов.
Вот Я и не знаю, что сообщает Python, когда встречает на своем пути вызов "time.sleep"

Comment: Другими словами. Что будет созданный Python процесс сообщать ОС после команды sleep: "Ставь на мое место другой процесс, Я свое отработал" или "Мое процессорное время еще не вышло! Я посплю тут, но мое ядро процессора не занимать!"

Comment: Насколько мне известно, реальной реализации потоков (threads) в питоне просто нет. Поэтому о мультипрограммировании на потоках в нем говорить не стоит.

Судя по разъяснениям к [Joining zombie processes](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) в \*nix интерпретатор просто делает `fork()` и исполняет код в новом процессе. Соответсвенно `sleep()` будет тем же самым sleep(), что и в обычной программе на  Си.


И подобных "диалогов" с ядром

 "Ставь на мое место другой процесс, ...."

в реальности просто не происходит.

Comment: В соусе python вроде как нашел реализацию метода 'time.sleep': 'Modules/timemodule.c', функция time_sleep (но основная логика находится в floatsleep). Как Вы и утверждали, там вызывается специфичный для платформы метод прерывания работы процесса, например для win32: Sleep()
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: > Насколько мне известно, реальной
> реализации потоков (threads) в питоне
> просто нет.

Там свой планировщик потоков для каждого процесса. В одно время может выполняться только один поток - управляющий, остальные ждут. Это есть Global Interpreter Lock.
Почему именно так реализовано, зачем Python сам распределяет время потоков на выполнение Я так и не понял :(

Comment: @uzumaxy, насколько знаю так было сделано специально.

Кроме этой реализации были и другие, но они каким-либо образом плохо влияли на производительность однопоточных приложений, поэтому Гвидо отказывался их принимать.

Это было его условием - такая реализация многопоточности, которая не ухудшает текущую производительность однопоточных приложений.